# Array copy in parallel_for_each context

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, copy, c++-amp

I’m *very* newbie in AMP C++. Everything works fine if I use ‘memcpy’ inside the ‘parallel_for_each’ function, but I do know it is not the best practice. I tried to use ‘copy_to’, but it raises an exception. Below follows a simplified code, focusing the issue, that I am having troubles. Thanks in advance.

```
typedef std::vector<DWORD> CArrDwData;

class CdataMatrix
{
public:
    CdataMatrix(int nChCount) : m_ChCount(nChCount)
    {
    }

    void SetSize(UINT uSize)
    {
        // MUST be multiple of m_ChCount*DWORD
        ASSERT(uSize%sizeof(DWORD) == 0);
        m_PackedLength = uSize/sizeof(DWORD);
        m_arrChannels.resize(m_ChCount*m_PackedLength);
    }

    UINT GetChannelPackedLen() const
    {
        return m_PackedLength;
    }
    const LPBYTE GetChannelBuffer(UINT uChannel) const
    {
        CArrDwData::const_pointer cPtr = m_arrChannels.data() + m_PackedLength*uChannel;

        return (const LPBYTE)cPtr;
    }

public:
    CArrDwData m_arrChannels;

protected:
    UINT m_ChCount;
    UINT m_PackedLength;
};

void CtypDiskHeader::ParalelProcess()
{
    const int nJobs = 6;
    const int nChannelCount = 3;
    UINT uAmount = 250000;
    int vch;

    CArrDwData arrCompData;

    // Check buffers sizes
    ASSERT((~uAmount & 0x00000003) == 3);   // DWORD aligned
    const UINT uInDWSize = uAmount/sizeof(DWORD);   // in size give in DWORDs

    CdataMatrix arrChData(nJobs);

    arrCompData.resize(nJobs*uInDWSize);
    vector<int> a(nJobs);
    for(vch = 0; vch < nJobs; vch++)
        a[vch] = vch;

    arrChData.SetSize(uAmount+16); // note: 16 bytes or 4 DWORDs larger than uInDWSize

    accelerator_view acc_view = accelerator().default_view;

    Concurrency::extent<2> eIn(nJobs, uInDWSize);
    Concurrency::extent<2> eOut(nJobs, arrChData.GetChannelPackedLen());

    array_view<DWORD, 2> viewOut(eOut, arrChData.m_arrChannels);

    array_view<DWORD, 2> viewIn(eIn, arrCompData);

    concurrency::parallel_for_each(begin(a), end(a), [&](int vch)
    {
        vector<DWORD>::pointer ptr = (LPDWORD)viewIn(vch).data();
        LPDWORD bufCompIn = (LPDWORD)ptr;
        ptr = viewOut(vch).data();
        LPDWORD bufExpandedIn = (LPDWORD)ptr;

        if(ConditionNotOk())
        {
            // Copy raw data bufCompIn to bufExpandedIn

            // Works fine, but not the best way, I suppose:
            memcpy(bufExpandedIn, bufCompIn, uAmount);

            // Raises exception:
            //viewIn(vch).copy_to(viewOut(vch));
        }
        else
        {
            // Some data processing here
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The has nothing to do with the `parallel_for_each` it looks like it is a known bug with `array_view::copy_to`. See the following post:

[Curiosity about concurrency::copy and array_view projection interactions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6587b844-771a-4aad-b039-bc0a8adacd05/curiosity-about-concurrencycopy-and-arrayview-projection-interactions?forum=parallelcppnative)

You can fix this using an explicit `view_as()` instead. I believe in your case your code should look something like this.

```
viewIn(vch).copy_to(viewOut(vch));

// Becomes...

viewIn[vch].view_as<1>(concurrency::extent<1>(uInDWSize)).copy_to(viewOut(vch));
```

I can't compile your example so was unable to verify this but I was able to get an exception from similar code and fix it using `view_as()`.

If you want to copy data within a C++ AMP kernel then you need to do it as assignment operations on a series of threads. The following code copies the first 500 elements of `source` into the smaller `dest` array.

```
array<int, 1> source(1000);
array<int, 1> dest(500);

parallel_for_each(source.extent, [=, &source, &dest](index<1> idx)
{
    if (dest.extent.contains(idx))
        dest[idx] = source[idx];
});
```

Comment: I've made a major mistake in my original post and I have just fixed it. The source and target arrays do not have the same extent. Sorry by the inconvenience and thank you for you reply. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. In the original code, the extent of viewOut(vch) is a little bit larger than viewIn(vch) extent. Using this way, it raises an exception 'runtime_exception'. When catching it, it supplies the following message xcp.what() = "Failed to copy because extents do not match".

I fixed the code replacing the original code by: viewIn(vch).copy_to(viewOut(vch).section(viewIn(vch).extent));
It copies only the source extent, that is what I need. But only compiles **without** restricted AMP.

Comment: You don't have any restrict specifiers in your code above. Furthermore you cannot use memcpy or copy_to inside restrict(amp) code because neither of them are themselves restrict(amp).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that my code isn't restrict(amp). Because that I wrote "But only compiles without restricted AMP". I would appreciate very much if you know an equivalent code that allow to perform that vector copy (input with smaller extent than output) compatible with the restrict(amp) directive. I've been searched the MSDN, but I was unlucky to find documentation containing vector copy exemplifications. Rgds.